# multiple JButton update cluttering the Swing thread

Tags: java, performance, swing, jbutton

I have 100,000 JButton instances that need to update 2 times per sec, each time with different values.
All the JButtons are showing at all times.

What I am seeing is the UI will lag: dragging, moving windows around.
Any way I can enhance the painting / setText process?

Comment: You'll probably have to paste some code. How are you updating? Also you might want to consider a lighter weight component than a JButton. Are all 100,000 JButtons visible?

Comment: I have to ask: why do you have 100,000 JButtons?

Comment: I just call setText(). Yes, they are all visible at all times.

Comment: Can't you replace them with one JTable with JButton based Renderer?

Comment: ....Or possibly replace with shapes in a single JPanel. I have to wonder if this is an XY Problem in disguise.

Comment: Basically with 100,000 JButtons there is always going to be a performance hit. There is very little you can do about that manipulating so many components. Agreed with the others, above - looks more like a design problem.

Comment: 100K buttons will not fit on a screen. What is the point of continually updating them since a user will never be able to follow the changes to all that data. When you need to render many components then you should probably use a JTable., which will only repaint cells that are visible on the screen.